# AWS Cognito signup

Tags: c#, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to follow the example for signing up a user in Cognito using C# from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/sign-up-and-confirm-with-user-pools-using-csharp/). I had to add some stuff because `AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient` doesn't have an empty constructor. My app happens to be a Xamarin Forms app, but that shouldn't matter. I tried doing it in a .NETStandard project but kept getting an error saying that the method doesn't exist. So I switched to a PCL and now I'm getting `System.IO.InvalidDataException: Cannot determine protocol`. I get this error on both Android and iOS.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task SignupUser(string username, string password, string email)
{
    const string UserPoolId = "us-east-1_XXXXXXXXX";
    const string ClientId = "6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    const string ClientSecret = "my-client-secret";
    const string CognitoIdentityPoolId = "us-east-1:identity-pool-id-here";

    try
    {
        AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderConfig providerConfig = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderConfig()
        {
            RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1
        };

        CognitoAWSCredentials cogCreds = new CognitoAWSCredentials(CognitoIdentityPoolId, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

        IdentityProvider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(cogCreds, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        SignUpRequest signUpRequest = new SignUpRequest()
        {
            ClientId = ClientId,
            Password = password,
            Username = username
        };
        AttributeType emailAttribute = new AttributeType()
        {
            Name = "email",
            Value = email
        };
        signUpRequest.UserAttributes.Add(emailAttribute);

        var signUpResult = await IdentityProvider.SignUpAsync(signUpRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Cannot determine protocol
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.SignRequest (Amazon.Runtime.IRequestContext requestContext) [0x0007a] in <e08989525980425e9b2f389f7417830e>:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.PreInvoke (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00013] in <e08989525980425e9b2f389f7417830e>:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.InvokeAsync[T] (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00000] in <e08989525980425e9b2f389f7417830e>:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeAsync[T] (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x0000e] in <e08989525980425e9b2f389f7417830e>:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.<>n__0[T] (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00000] in <e08989525980425e9b2f389f7417830e>:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever+<InvokeAsync>d__7`1[T].MoveNext () [0x00103] in <e08989525980425e9b2f389f7417830e>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler+<InvokeAsync>d__10`1[T].MoveNext () [0x000b0] in <e08989525980425e9b2f389f7417830e>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler+<InvokeAsync>d__10`1[T].MoveNext () [0x001b0] in <e08989525980425e9b2f389f7417830e>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler+<InvokeAsync>d__9`1[T].MoveNext () [0x00080] in <e08989525980425e9b2f389f7417830e>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler+<InvokeAsync>d__9`1[T].MoveNext () [0x00080] in <e08989525980425e9b2f389f7417830e>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler+<InvokeAsync>d__5`1[T].MoveNext () [0x00099] in <e08989525980425e9b2f389f7417830e>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler+<InvokeAsync>d__1`1[T].MoveNext () [0x000ab] in <e08989525980425e9b2f389f7417830e>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue sending "null" as credentials in `AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient` constructor:

```
IdentityProvider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(null, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
```

I don't know why but it works perfectly after that, no documentation found.

Comment: save my life, tks

Answer (score 0):

```
var region = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-west-2"); // use the region that you need
IdentityProvider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(null, region);
```